# How to Add a go service to an existing Apache server already serving PHP

Tags: apache, go

For an existing Apache server (Windows) that serves PHP, I want to add a go service that just contains REST endpoints, but need the existing PHP server to remain operational.

1) I cross compiled a go test application with a "/test" route and have it listening on port 8084

2) I am able to run the go application on the server, but when I accessed it directly with the IP address and port XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/test, nothing came back.

3) The Apache server is attached to port 80, with a domain name (fake) of aaa.bbb.com

Questions:
1) Does it matter which port I use?  (I chose 8084 for testing locally as I have a bunch of other services running)
2) Do I need to add anything to the httpd.conf file for the apache server so that the routes in the go app are automatically associated with the aaa.bbb.com domain?
3) Does it matter what folder I place the go exe file in?  (I realize it will need to be a service so that it executes on startup of the server, but just testing for now)

I have little experience on server setup, so apologize if my terminology is off a bit.

Comment: Is there a reason Apache is relevant here?  Are you aware that you can reach the Go application directly without needing Apache?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure apache to act as a proxy for the golang project.
Try something like this

```
ProxyPass /test http://0.0.0.0:8084/
ProxyPassReverse /test http://0.0.0.0:8084/
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: This will fix your problem. Than you can reach the GO services sending a request at @your_domain/test. The port is now 80 cause will be Apache that, acting as a proxy layer, will forward the request to the backend application